# Problem with geom_bar x axis tick or label

Tags: r, ggplot2, geom-bar

I'm trying to have a nice geom_bar but somehow it's now giving me what i want :

I tried many things and i got this visual problem which prevent my to have every  x value under every bar

Here is my code :

```
p<-ggplot(datapetite, aes(x= seq_along(Valeur), y = Pourcentage)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', aes(fill = Pourcentage > 0.05), position = 'dodge', col = 'transparent') + 
  theme_bw() + scale_fill_discrete(guide = 'none') +
  labs(title = "Petite Valeur", x = "Valeur", y = "Pourcentage")+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=percent) +
  scale_x_continuous(labels = datapetite$Valeur[seq_along(datapetite$Valeur)], breaks = datapetite$Valeur[seq_along(datapetite$Valeur)])
```

[image]

Thanks in advance

Comment: I don't have the data, but could you try `breaks = seq_along(datapetite$Valeur)` and see if that solves anything?

Comment: Thanks Teunbrand, it was just this line.  I lost so many times to make this work ...